# Odd printf behaviour after calling fread

Tags: c, bitmap, dos, bmp, watcom

I am trying to devise a function that will load bitmap images into memory and ultimately display it.
I am compiling the code with Watcom 16-bit C compiler with the target set to DOS. I am running the program in DOSBox.
The code is as follows:

```
#ifndef __BITMAP_H__
#define __BITMAP_H__

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct DIB
{
    int header_size;
    int px_width;
    int px_height;
}DIB_t;

DIB_t *load_bitmap(char *file_name)
{
    FILE *bmp_file;
    DIB_t *bitmap;
    char garbage[4];
    int c, file_size, pixel_offset;

    bitmap = (DIB_t*)malloc(sizeof bitmap);

    if(!bitmap)
    {
        perror("malloc()");
        return NULL;
    }

    bmp_file = fopen(file_name, "rb");

    if(!bmp_file)
    {
        perror("fopen()");
        return NULL;
    }

    c = fgetc(bmp_file);

    if(c == 'B')
    {
        c = fgetc(bmp_file);

        if(c == 'M')
        {
            fread(&file_size, 4, 1, bmp_file);
            fread(garbage, 1, 4, bmp_file);
            fread(&pixel_offset, 4, 1, bmp_file);
            fread(&bitmap->header_size, 4, 1, bmp_file);
            fread(&bitmap->px_width, 4, 1, bmp_file);
            fread(&bitmap->px_height, 4, 1, bmp_file);
            printf("BMP width: %dpx\nBMP Height: %dpx", bitmap->px_width, bitmap->px_height);
            fclose(bmp_file);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    fputs("File format not supported.\n", stderr);
    fclose(bmp_file);
    return NULL;
}
#endif
```

When you run this program it will output: "BMP width: %dpx\n" but nothing after the newline character??
I find this extremely odd. I have confirmed that none of the operations fail or set the errno and that px_height is actually set to it's appropiate value.
Is this something any of you have experience with?

Comment: Why? Do you expect something? If so post the relevant and code and tell us the expected behavior. I feel its incomplete with your current info

Comment: If it's a 16-bit C compiler, why are you reading 4 bytes into an `int` (*e.g.*, into `file_size`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only malloc'ing enough space for a pointer with this line

```
bitmap = (DIB_t*)malloc(sizeof(bitmap));
```

what you really need is

```
bitmap = (DIB_t*)malloc(sizeof(DIB_t));
```

Also, as mrbatch noted, you're using a 16 bit compiler and so attempting to read 4 bytes of data into 2 byte `int` variables. Make sure the sizeof() your types matches what you're reading, e.g. a `long int`

So - in general - you are corrupting both your stack and your heap by writing more data than you should, and you can expect your program to behave very oddly :)

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was some kind of memory corruption given that the program would crash when i tried reading the next two bytes into a short I added to the struct. Your answer will be accepted in 7 minutes :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Paul's answer to correct the `sizeof` for your `malloc`, try changing your `int` values to `long` in their declaration (I'm assuming you're code is correct about the bitmap containing 4 byte values to read). An `int` in a 16-bit compiler is going to be 2 bytes. You need a `long` (or equivalently `long int`) for a 4-byte value.

---

As suggested in the comments, even better would be to include `inttypes.h` and use `int32_t` instead of `int` or `long` to ensure a 32-bit value.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I am so used to integers being a 4-byte datatype that I take it for granted now.

Comment: @B01000100 yeah it's one of those "gotchas".

Comment: Don't change `int` to `long` but import _inttypes.h_ and use `int32_t` so you get a four byte integer on any platform.